# Is Bing Maps Terrain map style simply the Road style with a few captions?

Tags: c#, uwp, bing-maps

The crazy quilt of screen shots below shows, from left to right and top to bottom, the following Bing Map styles:

```
Road (top left)
Aerial (top right)
Terrain (middle left)
Aerial with Roads (middle right)
Aerial 3D (bottom left)
Aerial 3D with Roads (bottom right)
```

[image]

Is that all the Bing "Terrain" map style really is - the same thing as "Road" with a couple of captions added? Or is there something wrong with my code or something?

My code is:

```
const string road = "Road";
const string aerial = "Aerial";
const string aerialWithRoads = "Aerial with Roads";
const string terrain = "Terrain";
const string aerial3D = "Aerial 3D";
const string aerial3DWithRoads = "Aerial 3D with Roads";
```

. . .

```
cmbxMaptype.Items.Add(road);
cmbxMaptype.Items.Add(aerial);
cmbxMaptype.Items.Add(aerialWithRoads);
cmbxMaptype.Items.Add(terrain);
cmbxMaptype.Items.Add(aerial3D);
cmbxMaptype.Items.Add(aerial3DWithRoads);
```

. . .

```
private void cmbxMaptype_DropDownClosed(object sender, object e)
{
    switch (cmbxMaptype.SelectedValue)
    {
        case road:
            map.Style = MapStyle.Road;
            break;
        case aerial:
            map.Style = MapStyle.Aerial;
            break;
        case aerialWithRoads:
            map.Style = MapStyle.AerialWithRoads;
            break;
        case terrain:
            map.Style = MapStyle.Terrain;
            break;
        case aerial3D:
            map.Style = MapStyle.Aerial3D;
            break;
        case aerial3DWithRoads:
            map.Style = MapStyle.Aerial3DWithRoads;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the Terrain style for the bing map. If you still have questions about the bing map style, you could directly check the [bing map support](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/support)

Comment: The terrain MapStyle enumeration is a legacy way of setting the map style and currently has very few differences from the Road style. The preferred way of setting a map style is through the Stylesheet API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.StyleSheet, and it gives you complete control over what features are displayed. You can use the stylesheet editor application to preview map styles and customize, and it will generate the necessary code for you. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/map-style-sheet-editor/9nbhtcjt72ft